# How do I use textbox for input and output instead of using cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

```
SolverOk SetCell:="$I$35", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
    "$O$9:$S$28,$Q$5:$S$5", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverOk SetCell:="$I$35", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:= _
    "$O$9:$S$28,$Q$5:$S$5", Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverSolve
```

Normally, both inputs and outputs are shown in cells.
How do I change this to make it receive value from textboxes and show outputs on textboxes?

edit:this is an optimization problem inputs are transportation cost,outputs are items needed to be delivered from factory to retaliers in each province

Comment: That depends: what are your textboxes *named*?

Comment: i didn't,if i do i'll name them input11,input12,... like table

Comment: **[This tutorial](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-a-userform-to-aid-data-entry-in-excel/)** will walk you through the process.

Comment: thanks,that helps me